# Issues with getResource() after maven build

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to load a file from the resources folder, but I can't get it to work after build/packaging

```
URL databaseURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("blacklisted.words");
List<String> blacklistedWordsDatabase = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(databaseURL.getPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

This works perfectly when I run my code from the IDE, but after `mvn package` I run `java -jar target/project-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and get

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException file:/var/www/project/target/project-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/blacklisted.words
```

But checking the archive `blacklisted.words` is clearly in the root folder of the jar... Any tips on what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Files.readAllLines` which expects a real file / path. This will work in an "unpacked" environment like when you're testing in IDE or running `mvn test` / `mvn exec`, but won't work with JAR, where files are packed inside an archive. There are no files and paths!

What you can do instead is to get an `InputStream` of a packed resource and use it:

```
try (InputStream resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("blacklisted.words")) {
    List<String> blacklistedWordsDatabase = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            resource,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        )
    ).lines()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you, going with an InputStream worked great.